# Remove unused imports in Python 2.7 inside Atom Editor

Tags: python, atom-editor

Is there any available plugin to remove unused imports in Python 2.7 inside [Atom Editor]?[1](https://atom.io/)

I found [autoflake 1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autoflake) but it seems an independent program. I am looking for Atom Editor plugin to do the same.

As always. thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I am doing ROS development. in which I sometimes need to use C++ too. Sometimes some basic XML too. Hence I am sticking to Atom.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `linter-pylint` package, which shows unused imports after file save.

More info can be found on following link: https://atom.io/packages/linter-pylint

Comment: Please add more info from link to this post